# PHP: Define variables / array within a loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, variables

I've got this code

```
$vote = array(
    $arrayName[0][firstsector],
    $termin[1][firstsector],
    $termin[2][firstsector],
    $termin[3][firstsector]
);
```

Now I want to create a loop for it. I tried this:

```
$howMuchIneed = 5;

for ($x = 0; $x <= $howMuchIneed; $x++) {
    $vote = array(
        $arrayName[$x][firstsector]
    );
}
```

But the result doesn't look the same as the first code.

Comment: becuase you storing the value in $vote which is not an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this ?

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= $howMuchIneed; $x++) {
    array_push($vote, $arrayName[$x][firstsector]);
}
```

initializes Array

```
$vote = array();
```

If you want to learn more about **array_push** http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this (in your `for` loop):

```
$vote[] = $arrayName[$x]['firstsector'];
```

... and don't forget to declare your array before your loop!

`$vote = array();`

And in your first example you have 4 elements, condition in your `for` should be `$x < 4` - arrays in PHP are zero-based.